# Replace slash and number in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched stackoverflow but could find a solution I could replicate for my problem.

I got a url sting like:
http://localhost:8888/mypage/post/1/

The post number can be randomly ([0-9]).
Now I want to take that sting and change "post/1/" into "newpost/2/"
How can I make this happen with javascript or jQuery?

I tried the .replace function but couldn't figure out how to combine the characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to change just the number after `post/` or also change `post` into `newpost`?

Comment: basically it's just the number, but I want to make sure that it is the combination of  `post/` + `random number` and not any number that might occurre in the url.

Comment: I just noticed something. Are you suggesting changing the `1` into a `2`? Are we to assume they are adding one or multiplying by two?

Comment: Daerik already gave mit a fitting answer. I need to add 1 (++) to the current post number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript string [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:8888/mypage/post/1/';
var newUrl = url.replace(/post\/([0-9])\//, 'newpost/$1/');
console.log(newUrl);
```

Comment: thanks for that answer. I got a followup question: what is the `$` in `newpost/$1/` doing?

Comment: `([0-9])` though should be changed to: `([0-9]+)` for double-digits (10,11,12...)

Comment: `$n` (`$1`) is a way of identifying the rule inside of the parenthesis and allowing it to be extracted from the original string for use in the output string. If you had multiple parens (`()`) groups, you could use `$2`, `$3`, etc

Comment: @simey.me Couldn't agree more, but the OP specifically requested `([0-9])`. Without further instructions, I am to assume it is a single number in a range of 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`var old = "http://localhost:8888/mypage/post/1/";
 var new = old.replace("post/1/","newpost/2/");
 console.log(new);`

This logs "http://localhost:8888/mypage/newpost/2/".

If number after post is dynamic, create new strings based on the number and try replace function. [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8888/mypage/post/5/';

// increase number by 1
var number = url.match(/post\/([0-9]+)\//, 'newpost/$1/');
number = parseInt(number[1]);
number++;

// replace matches in string
var newUrl = url.replace(/post\/([0-9])\//, 'newpost/' + number + '/');
console.log(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control then you could split your string into an array and edit individual values, then convert back to string:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8888/mypage/post/1/';
var urlArray = url.split("/");
urlArray[4] = "newpost";
urlArray[5] = "2"; // will also work with a number
var newUrl = urlArray.join("/");
```